# Are molecules on surface of liquid stationary due to surface tension

Tags: physical-chemistry

Are the molecules which are on the surface of a liquid ie the molecules on the top film stationary ie not move about each other under steady conditions ie unlike molecules in the bulk because of surface tension and because surface acts like a stretched film and leaving or coming to the surface for any molecule requires gain or loss of energy ?

Comment: While it is true that additional forces (surface tension) are at play at the surface, in general that will not require that the molecules be stationary there. They just see a slightly different potential, and will move slightly differently. For example, consider how a 'stationary' molecule would evaporate?